# How to keep focus on first thread when using AttachThreadInput?

Tags: c++, winapi

I found that by utilizing the APIs [`AttachThreadInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-attachthreadinput) and `SetFocus()`, I was able to click on a specific window when it's in the background, however it stole the focus from the first thread `guiThreadID` to the second `target_window`, and this happens **only** in case `guiThreadID` is currently focused.

If I have any *other* window focused while running the code, it doesn't get the focus stolen. The goal is to be able to click in the background window without activating it.

What can I try to avoid it stealing focus from the first thread?

```
HWND target_window = FindWindow(L"Test", NULL);

DWORD guiThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId();

bool threads_are_attached = false;
DWORD target_thread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(target_window, NULL);
if (target_thread && target_thread != guiThreadID && !IsWindowHung(target_window))
    threads_are_attached = AttachThreadInput(guiThreadID, target_thread, TRUE) != 0;

SetFocus(target_window);

auto lParam = MAKELPARAM(150, 700);
PostMessageW(target_window, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0x0001, lParam);
PostMessageW(target_window, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, lParam);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "by utilizing AttachThreadInput and SetFocus, I was able to click on a specific window when it's in the background." You can click on a window in the background without having to use AttachThreadInput and SetFocus. Just use the mouse and click.

Comment: @RaymondChen I forgot to mention that the goal is to be able to click in the background window without activating it. In my `target_window` sending `PostMessage` with `WM_LBUTTONDOWN/UP` has no effect unless the window is focused, I could see using spy++ that the window receives the msg, however, the click doesn't get fired, but utilizing the method above I could 'bypass' the focus requirement, the cons are losing the focus from the first thread window, and this only happens on the `guiThreadID` window, if I have any other window focused and run the code it doesn't get her focus stolen.

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). Since, apparently, you're trying to automate a UI you shouldn't preemtively avoid the standard solution: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: Im not sending keystrokes just click, i know about UI Automation but it will not help in my case as im sending click on different positions and not on a specific window control.

Comment: Modify the `target_window`'s code so it accepts mouse input when not active. Or even better, add a custom API so you can ask the target window to do the thing directly, no simulated input required. (If you didn't write the target window, then you can try to use UI Automation, assuming the target window supports it. It's all hacks at this point. The target window might have a `if (!active) ignore_all_input()`. Worst case, run the program in a VM. That way, it is just the active window in the VM and doesn't affect your main system.)

Comment: @RaymondChen meeting elon musk or whoever? no thanks. meeting raymond chen? name the price, im 17yo, start programming 2y ago, and im already a big fan yours, your blog has help me learning a lot of things, few days ago i wrote a question about scrollbars and i mentioned `the scrollbar series` in your blog, never thought one day you would be asking one of my questions I'd appreciate if you could take a look at this. - My apologies for being off-topic it will not be repeated. -